# Can you decorate a hexadecimal constant so it's interpreted as a float?

Tags: opengl, casting, floating-point, hex, integer-division

Just curious about something. While converting HTML colors (whose individual color components are represented via 2-digit hexadecimal values) to floats between 0.0 and 1.0 so we can use them with OpenGL, I became curious about something.  We have to divide the hex values by 255 to give us their OpenGL counterparts, but we can't simply use the hex values as-is because that produces integer division.

Now I know these all work around this issue (of course)...

```
float r = 0xFD / (float)0xFF; // Works because of the cast to float

float r = 0xFD / 255.0f;      // Works because of the explicit float 

float d = 0xFF;
float r = 0xFD / d;           // Works because 'd' is a float
```

...but I was wondering if there's any way to just decorate a hex value so it's interpreted as a float (like you do with the 'f' in 1.0f) without having to do casting, calculations or interim variables.

These of course don't work...

```
float r = 0xFD / 0xFF;   // Integer division yields an integer, not float

float r = 0xFD / 0xFFf;  // Interprets 'f' as part of the hex value
```

Again, not trying to find out how to achieve my needed results as my code works just fine.  I'm just wondering if I can make the code cleaner via decorating the hex value with something similar to how 'f' works with decimal values instead of using the above-three methods that do work.

Comment: I'm curious: why are you using literals in your shader often enough to matter? How often do you have need of a specific constant color?

Comment: Not a shader.  Never said it was and is actually a completely different part of the program unrelated to rendering at all (except that I'm defining colors.)  Still, that's irrelevant to the question.  Forget I even mentioned OpenGL.  I'm just looking to see if there's any way to decorate hex.  I guess consider this more a compiler-related question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you have to use preprocessor definition in order to achieve the best look. And you need also casting to perform your computations.

The best solution I can think is

```
#define COMPONENT8(value) ((float)(value) / 255.0f))
```

Floating point values cannot be specified as hexadecimal (integer) values.

Comment: While this doesn't answer my specific question, I didn't even think of using the define to actually house the actual entire equation like that!  Very cool! (...although I think I'll call it `NormalizeHex` or something like that since that's what it's actually doing.)  BUT... why are you casting `value` to a float?  Won't the fact that the denominator ('255.0f' here) be enough to force the entire thing to be float-division?  I mean it's just a cast, but I don't think it's actually needed.

Comment: Then again, now that I think about it (and the reason I didn't think of doing this before...) is why wouldn't you just use an inline function instead of a define here?  When it gets inlined, isn't the actual compiled result basically the same thing?

Comment: any comment on the define vs inlined function?  I voted yours as the answer, but I'm still curious as to why you'd do it that way.  Only thing I can think of is a define only needs a header file whereas an inline function needs a code file too.  Plus, you get full type-checking with an inline function as well.

Comment: Yes, it is just a cast. I prefer preprocessor because I feel it more comfortable, but I don't see any limitation about inlined functions...

Answer (score 1):

This would likely be possible in c++0x using [user defined literals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#User-defined_literals) but I doubt there is any neat way to do it in c++03.

Comment: Never heard of c++0x, but just found the Wikipedia article on it.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x  Really cool stuff!  Voted up!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to do exactly what you're asking, but if you're looking to use 0xFF repeatedly, why not set it as a constant? That will still preserve typing, i.e:

```
const float divisor = 0xFF
float r = 0xFD / divisor
```

I think that'd solve the issue you're looking to solve, even if it's not exactly in the same way.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to solve that issue. I'm trying to find if there's a way to decorate a hex value to make it a float.  What you're showing is just good programming (albeit programming 101) but because of your answer, I'll change the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is by defining your own pattern to define hex floats, 0xff defines hex integers, you could make a macro, like:

```
#define 0y (float) 0x
```

Then you just write

```
float r = 0xAF / 0yFF;
```

to do your float division.

This solution could though create confusion for others who reads your code, but if the code is mostly for you, than you could do it this way

Comment: This looked pretty damn cool when I read it... but... doesn't work!  First, apparently you can't start a define with a number, and second, it doesn't like the '0x' portion stating that it doesn't recognize 'x' as an integer modifier. Plus, without the space after `0y` it doesn't match the define.  Man... I soooo wanted to mark this one as accepted for being so simply elegant.  Guess it was just too simple.  Lemme know if you get this to work. (FYI, I tried `#define f0x (float)0x` but to no avail for the aforementioned reasons.)

Comment: Oh, that sucks. Well I got no possibility to test anything atm since im at work, but I might give it a look when I get home tonight.